# How to make category templates, pages and index appear in the same menu in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having some problems structuring a Wordpress Website.
Basically this website will have the following pages:

- Home
- Portfolio
- News
- Contact

The home will be designed by the index.php, that is no problem. In this page I will show some of the posts that should be in the News and some that should appear in Portfolio.
The pages Portfolio and News should present a list of posts that match this category.
Contact is a normal static page.

My idea was to create a static page for portfolio and for news and to change its theme so I get a list of posts matching this category and handle it. But I found out that this does not work as I thought because pages are not meant to this. For this reason some functions (as the_content) do not work. So I found about Category Templates, which seem exactly what I want.
But now my problem is: my menu is being built automatically and I find it nice. Using the category page template would cause me to need to build it manually, which looks like (for a newbie) a bad smell, once it can be built automatically.

Is the approach with Home->index.php, news and portfolio -> category template and contact -> static page a nice approach?
How would I build the menu in a elegant way with this approach?

Thanks!
Oscar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your approach was the best, I would have used [page templates](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) to pull the different layout/type of pages and use the front-page.php to create the homepage.

But every dev has his own way, I guess.

I think you can easily solve your problem building the menu with the built-in menu builder of wordpress. You can go in Appearance > Menu if your theme is compatible with that.

[Check further documentation here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

hope it helps!
cheers

Comment: I am new to WP, so I didn't know about the front-page.php. I will look for info about it and find out the difference between it and index.php.
About the page templates part, this was actually my first choice, but in the "news" section, I would have to iterate over all the posts in the "news" category and show its title and content. But iI read that the static page template does not work correctly with the_content and the more tag

Comment: After answering it here I looked for more info and I found this: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/the_content-ignores-lt-more-gt-when-using-get_posts-and-setup_postdata?replies=5 . Adding the more=0 works and my static page template now breaks the post on the more tag :)

Comment: Cool Oscar! Glad you manage to solve the problem, and learn along the way! I'm also more or less new to WP dev, still learning everyday. cheers

Answer (score 0):

In wordpress you can add static page or categories or any other pages to wordpress menu. For creating menu in wordpress see this links.
[creating menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel#Categories)